# AsyncTaskMethodBuilder AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted vs AwaitOnCompleted on await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

When `await` is encountered by the compiler it transforms the `async` method to a state machine and the continuation is scheduled via

`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted` as outlined [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation) or `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AwaitOnCompleted` as outlined [here](http://azuredeveloper.co.il/?p=474).

Looking through .NET source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,7f50b26fa800b792), 
`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted` calls `Awaiter.UnSafeOnCompleted`

It appears that `Awaiter.UnSafeOnCompleted` does not flow the ExecutionContext (code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,f0806708df510210)).

Notice it passes `false` to `flowExecutionContext`. This means if I am using `LogicalCallContext` (part of `ExecutionContext`) to store any data (e.g. activityId) then it wont be flowed in continuation path which means I cannot access it.

So, my question is **what causes the compiler to choose Unsafe Completion** ?

Stephen Toub also mentioned the same thing [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/) but did not give any details.
*"All of the methods in the .NET Framework that fork asynchronous work capture and restore ExecutionContext in a manner like this (that is, all except for those prefixed with the word “Unsafe,” which are unsafe because they explicitly do not flow ExecutionContext"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This means if I am using `LogicalCallContext` [...] to store any data [...] then it wont be flowed in continuation path

Not exactly. `OnCompleted` is just one of the possible ways for the execution context to flow. You'd need to rule out the other ways in which it may flow.

> So, my question is what causes the compiler to choose Unsafe Completion ?

The compiler will use this whenever possible (i.e. whenever `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` is implemented).

However, the compiler also relies indirectly on `AsyncMethodBuilderCore`, and this does cause the execution context to flow, through its [`MoveNextRunner`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,c7b2691b131812c7) helper class. This manages to do it, in this case, more efficiently, by only storing a single reference to the execution context, rather than one reference for each continuation.

Unless you're going out of your way to prevent the execution context from flowing, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Pretty impressive answer. As far as I can tell the gory implementation details supporting the "whenever `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` is implemented" statement can be found in Roslyn's [AsyncMethodToStateMachineRewriter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d4dab355b96955aca5b4b0ebf6282575fad78ba8/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/AsyncRewriter/AsyncMethodToStateMachineRewriter.cs)